# New endpoints in Node Express + Typescript app are not called

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm new with Node express. I'm building a fairly simple CRUD app for pets.

I have 2 endpoints that work, and whenever I create any new endpoint, Postman won't recognise them, and I get a 404 back. I can even comment out the 2 working endpoints and they'll still work

The two endpoints that work are

```
// simplest request
app.get('/', (request: Request, response: Response) => {
  response.send('Express + TypeScript Server');
});

// and
app.get('/pets', (request: Request, response: Response) => {
```

the below don't work at all. they get me a 404 error in Postman:

```
app.get('/ayo', (request: Request, response: Response) => {
  response.send("ayo");

// and

app.get("pets/:id", (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

// and just about anything else
});
```

Another strange thing is that my error handlers are never called:

```
// Use the 404 handler
app.use(handle404NotFound);

// Use the 500 handler
app.use(handle500GenericError);
```

I think maybe there's a glitch happening somewhere. I tried closing and opening the IDE several times. here's my index.ts:

```
import express, {Express, NextFunction, Request, Response} from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import fs from 'fs';
import {handle404NotFound, handle500GenericError} from './error/ErrorHandler';
import {Constant} from './utils/Constant';
import {Pet} from './model/Pet';

dotenv.config();

const app: Express = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

// simplest request
app.get('/', (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    response.send('Express + TypeScript Server');
});

app.get('/ayo', (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    response.send("ayo");
});

// get all pets
app.get('/pets', (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    response.json(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/pets.json', {encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r'})));
});

// get single detailed pet

app.get("/pets/:id", (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const pets = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/pets.json', {encoding: "utf8", flag: "r"}));
        const pet = pets.find((p: Pet) => p.id === parseInt(request.params.id));

        if (!pet) {
            return response.status(404).json({message: 'Pet not found'});
        }

        pet.dateAdded = new Date(pet.dateAdded);
        response.json(pet);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        next(error);
    }
});

// if the environment is in testing, only then can this function be run
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
    app.get(Constant.THROW_500_ERROR_ENDPOINT, (request, response, next) => {
        throw new Error();
    })
}

// Use the 404 handler
app.use(handle404NotFound);

// Use the 500 handler
app.use(handle500GenericError);

// export the app object
export default app;

// Don't start the server if tests are running
if (require.main === module) {
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`⚡️[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're not restarting the app when making changes. FYI you want `'/pets/:id'`, not `'pets/:id'` or `'/pets:id'`

Comment: thanks. i made the change, still the same problem

Comment: But did you restart your Express app?

Comment: yeah absolutely. i was doing that all the time. you meant stopping the server then going "npm start"? yeah definitely

Comment: That's right. So each time you start the server, do you see the `⚡️[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:<some port>` message?

Comment: correct that's what I see yes. I even restarted the IDE, even switched IDEs. saved the files, compiled them

Comment: Ok, so what port is it listening on? Are you 100% sure you're running the code shown in this question? Try changing that listen message to see if it also changes when you start the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257268/discussion-between-meniman98-and-phil).

Comment: From the comments in chat it seems pretty clear now that you're not running this code at all

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that my index.ts file was inside a src folder. I moved the index.ts outside the src folder, and now all changes are reflected correctly